# Javascript 2 Decimal Float Concats Instead of adding

Tags: javascript

Just Trying to Parse some numbers I'm getting some end up with 2 Decimals. The Input gets pushed out as a string to the page so I need to parse it to use it.

But for some reason, my Total Value is getting concatenated instead of the 2 values being added. Removing the .toFixed(); Has intended behaviour Excluding the wanted decimal points. Added it causes the values to concat.

```js
function update() {
                var servicefee = 1300;
                        var select = document.getElementById('select-visa');
                var cost = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

                var total = parseInt(servicefee) + parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML =  total;
            }
```

```html
<select id="select-visa" class="selectpicker "  onChange="update()" aria-label="Default select example" >
    <option value="1725,52">Example 1</option>
    <option value="200">Example 2</option>
    
 </select>
    

<p id="total"></p>
```

Would appreciate it if you could explain why adding decimal points to the float causes this behaviour.

Comment: `toFixed()` change the number to a `string`. When adding `string` with `number`, the `number` automatically get converted to a `string` and two `string`s get concated. Use `toFixed()` only after you have finished all calculation. If you really want to round a number without convert it to string, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) return string as response. Adding a string to a number will typecast the result to string.

So you should set total as

```
var total = parseInt(servicefee) + +parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);
```

The `+` symbol infront of `+parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);` will convert the string to number.

Or else you can perform the addition and add `.toFixed(2)` to the `total` to keep the decimal places in the final result

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function update() {
    var servicefee = 1300;
    var select = document.getElementById('select-visa');
    var cost = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var total = parseInt(servicefee) + parseFloat(cost);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML =  total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<select id="select-visa" class="selectpicker "  onChange="update()" aria-label="Default select example" >
    <option value="1725.52">Example 1</option>
    <option value="200">Example 2</option>
</select>
    
<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: Something I forgot to add to the qeustion was how do i get it to keep the trailing 0 on the decimal i Just think its easier to read that way.  Im assuming id have to convert back to a string and use .toFixed Btw thanks for the answer

Comment: you can perform the addition and add .toFixed(2) to the total to keep the decimal places in the final result. I have updated the answer